# Argument of type 'HttpErrorResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I'm trying to get a global HTTP interceptor working.

We have two interceptors, one for client side errors and the below for server side errors.

I want to try and throw an error of type HttpErrorResponse, so that this error is not picked up by the client side error catcher.

However with the below, the TypeScript compiler is throwing an error of:

```
Error: errors/http-error.interceptor.ts:26:37 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'HttpErrorResponse' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ error?: any; headers?: HttpHeaders | undefined; status?: number | undefined; statusText?: string | undefined; url?: string | undefined; }'.
  Types of property 'url' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

26         throw new HttpErrorResponse(error);
                                       ~~~~~
```

I've tried tweaking the types of the parameter and the return type.

Where am I going wrong here?

```
import {
  HttpHandler,
  HttpRequest,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpErrorResponse,
  HttpInterceptor
} from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { catchError } from "rxjs/operators";
import { SnackbarService } from "../services/snackbar.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private snackbarService: SnackbarService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        this.snackbarService.openError(`An error has occurred. Status: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`);
        throw new HttpErrorResponse(error);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new instance? Just `throw error;`

Comment: Nowadays: ```return throwError(() => new HttpErrorResponse(error));```

Answer (score 1):

`catchError` is a rxjs operator and expects that you return and Observable not just throw a plain JavaScript error. What you should do is to use another rxjs operator `throwError` and return it like this
`return throwError(error);`

You might also just return an empty Observable, if you don't want to process the error further and only show your notification.